# Filepond React: Revert call does not contain any id

Tags: reactjs, filepond

Bear with me, I've looked at the similar questions but they are of no help.

The React filepond project works great for uploading images, but reverting is not working. The DELETE call does not send to the server which file is actually being deleted. That makes it impossible to clean up files that the user does not want to be uploaded.

Here is my React Code.

```
return <FilePond 
  labelIdle={label}
  name={name}
  files={files}
  allowMultiple={maxFiles !== 1}
  maxFiles={maxFiles}
  server={{
    process: {
      url: baseURL + `/${name}/image`,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        userid
      },
    },
    revert: baseURL + `/${name}/image/revert`
  }}
  onremovefile={(err: any, file: any) => {
    debugger
  }}
  onupdatefiles={(fileItems: any) => onUpdateFiles(fileItems.map((fileItem: any) => fileItem.file))}
/>
```

The cURL request looks like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:4000/tenant/image/revert' -X DELETE -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/tenant' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed
```

As you can see in the cURL request there is no ID being sent to the server.

Comment: Does your process call return a unique file id?

Comment: hi Rik, yes that was indeed the issue, but the symptom was very strange that Filepond did not send anything back with the revert call